# Сдвиг ячеек массива

Tags: java

Есть массив `int[10000]`. Нужно сдвинуть каждый элемент на 360 ячеек назад, при этом элементы `[0-359]` должны перенестись из начала в конец массива.
Написал алгоритм, но что-то подсказывает, что это ненужный велосипед, который к тому же и занимает много времени.
Если ли какая-то стандартная функция в Java, которая позволяет сделать это быстро, или необходимо самому писать цикл?

Comment: Скорее всего сделать класс-обертку, который просто будет отсчитывать сдивг внутри, будет проще, быстрее и эффективнее, нежели перемещать не самые минимальные объемы данных

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

- Сделать копию первых 360 элементов (`Arrays.copyOf`)
- Сдвинуть элементы в массиве на 360 влево (`System.arraycopy`)
- Вставить копию в последние 360 элементов (`System.arraycopy`)

Итоговый код:

```
final int shift = 360;
int[] array = IntStream.range(0, 10000).toArray();

int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, shift);
System.arraycopy(array, shift, array, 0, array.length - shift);
System.arraycopy(copy, 0, array, array.length - shift, shift);
```

---

Можно также рассмотреть варианты с использованием `Collections.rotate`:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.rotate(list, -shift);
array = list.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).toArray();
```

и просто `IntStream`:

```
array = stream(array);

private static int[] stream(int[] array, int shift)
{
    return IntStream.concat(
                IntStream.range(shift, array.length),
                IntStream.range(0, shift)
            )
            .map(e -> array[e])
            .toArray();
}
```

Однако по производительности эти варианты уступают первому.

Массив из 10 миллионов чисел:

```
arraycopy       5ms
collections   410ms
intstream      35ms
```

Массив из 100 миллионов чисел:

```
arraycopy      40ms
collections 20000ms
intstream     190ms
```

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то, что я искал

Comment: @Denis422 на здоровье. Я ещё пару вариантов добавил, но, как по мне, стоит остановиться на первом.